# How to configure IntelligentTieringConfiguration for an AWS::S3::Bucket resouce?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to write a CloudFormation template to configure an AWS S3 bucket with intelligent tiers configuration, and have read [AWS::S3::Bucket IntelligentTieringConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-intelligenttieringconfiguration.html) link. However it's not clear where to put in in the YAML file.

I have a template file, and run an AWS CLI command

```
$ aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name test-s3 --template-body file://test-s3.yaml --region us-east-1
```

I've tried

```
Description: AWS Cloudformation template to create S3 buckets
Resources:
  S3Bucket0:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    IntelligentTieringConfiguration:
      Id: Tier1
      Status: Enabled
      Tiering:
        - ARCHIVE_ACCESS
```

...which gives this error from AWS CLI immediately.

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Invalid template resource property 'IntelligentTieringConfiguration
```

...or...

```
Description: AWS Cloudformation template to create S3 buckets
Resources:
  S3Bucket0:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      IntelligentTieringConfiguration:
        Id: Tier1
        Status: Enabled
        Tiering:
          - ARCHIVE_ACCESS
```

...which gives this error in the AWS CloudFormation console.

```
Encountered unsupported property IntelligentTieringConfiguration
```

So what's the correct format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see some of these errors inline while authoring templates along with autocompletion and documentation links:

[image: Visual Studio Code extension]

```
[cfn-lint] E3002: Invalid Property Resources/S3Bucket0/Properties/IntelligentTieringConfiguration
```

Should look more like this:

```yaml
Resources:
  S3Bucket0:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      IntelligentTieringConfigurations:
        - Id: Tier1
          Status: Enabled
          Tierings:
            - AccessTier: ARCHIVE_ACCESS
              Days:
```

Comment: Thanks Pat. Yeah `aws cloudformation validate-template` just doesn't cut it.

Comment: I don't want to configure it, but I just want the default set-up. Any hints on how to just "enable" it? :)